# MapView annotation indexPath?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, annotations, mkmapview

Is there a method (or any way) you can get the "index path" of the annotation inside the method:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id)annotation
```

What I want to do is get something inside an array according to the annotation. One of the methods I think that I want to copy is `- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and use the "indexPath".

Searched a lot but not found any result. Or maybe I'm just bad at searching. Any reference will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you just want an array of the annotations can't u make use of `mapView.annotations` which gives an array of the annotations.

Comment: I need to get the data outside of the annotation (from a different data set) so just getting the annotations won't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer my own question (this how it works for me):

I created an instance in the custom annotation and transferred the data there, then inside `- mapView:viewForAnnotation:` (I used custom pinView) I imported and created an instance of my CustomAnnotation and got the data from there.

```
[customAnnotation setSomething: data];
```

```
- mapView:viewForAnnotation:
{
    pinView = [[[CustomPinView alloc] initWithAnnotation: annotation reuseIdentifier: PinIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

```
- initWithAnnotation:reuseIdentifier:
{
    CustomAnnotation *customAnnotation = (CustomAnnotation *)annotation;

    [customAnnotation something];
}
```

Overkill for me but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSUInteger index = [mapView.annotations indexOfObject:annotation];
```

Since the underlying array is a mutable one, note that the `index` can change. This seems to be the closest `indexPath` like information you can get.

Comment: Yes it is, but as noted, index are changing and it won't work (or mostly won't work). There are times that it's getting an info from a different index. Another thing is that if the user location is on, you should transfer the annotations to an NSMutableArray and remove it first (index: 0).